# Why does every PC hang for some seconds when you insert a DVD?

Tags: windows, dvd

For years and years I noticed that every PC (Windows XP and Windows 7) kind of stops for some seconds when you insert a DVD. It seems that the DVD initializing process takes over the entire operating system. Or the hard-drive?

Can somebody explain why this is happening?

I know, that this is a quite basic question but I couldn't find an answer online.

Thanks.

Comment: What operating system? I have been using Linux for over 8 years on very different machines and can't say that.

Comment: Haven't noticed it on Windows either. Only shows the loading cursor for a few seconds, but the computer stays fully operational during that.

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot to mention it. I experienced that behaviour on Windows XP and Windows 7. Added this information to the question. @positivew Well, this is what I mean with "hangs", the loading cursor appears for x seconds and you cannot do anything during this time.

Comment: That's what I thought, but as I said, I've never noticed it hanging, I can do what I want during that time. Approximately, on how many computers have you noticed this behavior?

Comment: I think it is due to _auto-run_, looking at the DVD and at the disk for what to handle it with. Try disabling _auto-run_ and see it disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question why Windows waits is simple. It is because the Basic IO System works with *interrupts* which causes the system to halt. This is also the case using external USB flash drives etc. but there you barely notice a hang because these devices are faster in reading/writing than CD/DVD.

The other question is why is it handled by interrupts. I think that has to do with a design question: do you want to have a computer which is constantly asking your CD/DVD-Drive whether there is something to read, even though most of the time there isn't a disk inserted? I think not.

The other way of knowing if there is something to read is to send a system interrupt and in the Interrupt Routine handle the things needed so the system knows where to read what.

So the PC engineers have chosen the second way (as I probably would have)

This is just a very narrowed down short version and isn't 100% correct but it should basically show you why. I hope this helps.

Comment: it helps, thanks for the explanation, now it is clear to me ;)